# How to pass build artifact into another job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, parameterized

### Setup

I have two jobs in Jenkins:

- `build master` - this builds the code and creates an artifact
- `deploy master` - this deploys the artifact

Currently, `deploy master` has "Copy artifacts from another project" build step using "latest successful build".

[image: build-master]

### My Goal

I want to change this step from "latest successful build" to "specified by a build parameter" so that I can select a specific build when deploying without modifying the configuration of `deploy master` job each time.

### What I've tried

First, I changed to "specified by a build parameter".

[image: build-specific]

Then I checked the box next to "This project is parameterized" and added a string parameter for `BUILD_SELECTOR`.

[image: parameter]

Then I selected build and enter the input `47` which is a build number from the `build master` job.

Additionally I tried the api call

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://jenkins/job/deploy%20master/build?token=abc7f5abc0c45abcea0646ed858abcde&BUILD_SELECTOR=47'
});
```

### Result

Both times it failed with the following output:

```
Started by user styfle
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\jobs\deploy master\workspace
ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: build master
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

### Question

How do I configure this properly so I can specify a build number (or some other identifier) when deploying?

### Update with solution

My solution thanks to Gerold's answer was to add a "Build selector for Copy Artifact" parameter and use a new environment variable to link to my string parameter I already added.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is just one workspace per project/job in Jenkins. The directories of builds contain just information about the builds and their results.

The root directories of both are specified in *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>.

To deploy an artifact of a previous build you have to copy it to somewhere else in `build master` and access it there from `deploy master` later.

**UPDATE:**

See the inline help for *Which build* → *Parameter Name*:

> *A parameter with this name should be added in the build parameters section above. There is a special parameter type for choosing the build selector.*

Use this ***Build selector for Copy Artifact*** instead of a *String Parameter*.

Comment: The `build master` job has a "Post-build Action" of "Archive the artifacts". And I have been able to specify a build by number by editing the config. So I know this part works.

Comment: @styfle The _Archive the artifacts_ _post-build action_ stores the specified files in `<mentioned system configuration>/<build no.>/archive/...` accessible via `http://<Jenkins>/job/<job name>/<build no.>/artifact/...`.

Comment: That url works. Should I try using the full URL as a parameter in the deployment?

Comment: @styfle If the artifact name doesn't change the `build no.` should be sufficient. It's the only variable in the URL.

Comment: I tried the build number 47 as a parameter and it doesn't work (see my original post). Yet, visiting the URL https://jenkins/job/build%20master/47/artifact/ does work.

Comment: @styfle See the inline help for _Which build_ → _Parameter Name_:  "_There is a special parameter type for choosing the build selector._". Use this instead of a _String Parameter_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113170/discussion-between-styfle-and-gerold-broser).

Comment: is there a way to copy the archived artifact in the deploy job? I am using the *Copy artifacts from another project* but that copies the unarchived artifact from the build workspace.

Comment: @Radu See _File/Folder Copy_ of the [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin).

Comment: how can I get the buildNumber from BUILD_SELECTOR?

Answer (score 7):

Add following in downstream project.
"Build selector for Copy Artifact" instead of a "String Parameter"

[image: "Build selector for Copy Artifact" instead of a "String Parameter"!!]

Copy artifacts from another project

[image]

Thats it. Click "Build with Parameters" and pass build number
[image]

Comment: Any idea why it's necessary to specify the upstream project name in the copy step, when the upstream job / build should already have been fully identified by the build selector?