# Deploy promoted builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, promoted-builds

I have two Jenkins tasks, one that builds and promotes the successful build, and another task that deploys those promoted builds. I'm using two plugins to accomplish this task, **Copy Artifact Plugin** and  **promoted builds**.

The job that I have to build the code is a very standard one, I go to the git repository every minute to check for any changes, and if there are any changes I just **Invoque Gradle Script** on the **Build** step and select **Use Gradle Wrapper** box and everything builds without a problem. The only custom part of this build task is that I'm using **promoted builds** plugin, which works great and have a very standard configuration as well.

[Build Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndoyK.png)

I'm happy with my **Build** task, but I have a problem with my **Deploy** task. In my *deploy* task I want to select which promoted build I want to deploy, but I can't deploy the selected promoted build.

In my *Deploy task* I tick the **This project is parameterised** box and I selected the **Promoted Build Parameter**.

[Promoted Build Parameter Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se04t.png)

The configuration looks ok, when I run the **Deploy** task I can select which build I want to deploy.

[Select build to be deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpe8B.png)

The problem that I have is when I select **Copy artifacts from another project**. In *Which build* I select *Specified by a build parameter* and for the *Parameter Name* I selected the same name I gave to the *Promoted Build Parameter*

[Copy artifacts from another project Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dAWt.png)

But when I run this *Deploy* task I get this error: `ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: Aurora`.

**BUT** if I change the *Which build* part to **Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build** everything works fine.

[Working Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adJSq.png)

What am I doing wrong in this configuration?

Comment: In order to help with your questions, It would be very helpful if you create a docker image with your jenkins tasks (with examples of course).  Your question is something extensive and has a lot of configurations. Check this link with preconfigured jenkins tasks : https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/9ebc80d18b9d40c959708c2582d47452

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing as these guys [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486244/how-to-pass-build-artifact-into-another-job-in-jenkins), just to make sure I was able to reproduce the exact same thing, but is still returning the same error `ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from:...`. Maybe I'm missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, I don't think it was the cleanest way of doing it but at the end it worked. In the **Build** task I left everything as it was, I only added a *Post-Build Action* to **Archive the artifacts**.

[Post Build Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNJcg.png)

In the **Deploy** task I needed to change a bit more stuff. In my Deploy task I tick the *This project is parameterised* box and I selected the **Promoted Build Parameter**, the configuration for this step is a very standard one, I just selected the *Build* project and the rest is automatic. This step enables me to select which promoted build I want to deploy, but this is where the big problem resides. The value that this "step" returns is something like this *https://site.name.com/job/ProjectName/137/*.

The problem that this create is in **Copy artifacts from another project**. I need a build number, but I only have that *URL*, so the solution that I found was to get the build number from that URL, inject that number as a local variable and use that local variable in the next steps.

[Build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lugoQ.png)

With this solution I'm able to deploy only the promoted build.