# Pass Jenkins build artifact as parameter to another plan

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem with artifact transferring from source build to triggered build.

**What I have**

- Jenkins plan A creates artifact;
- Jenkins plan A calls build on other project (plan B) and pass some parameters, includes file's location as file.zip=path_to_artifact/*.zip;
- Triggered Jenkins plan B takes the parameters and failed - it doesn't found the .zip artifact. I as understood, such parameter passing is unsupported.

P.S.: Jenkins plan B has file parameter as file.zip.

**Question**

How I can solve this problem?
Is it possible to solve it without pipeline script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass build artifact into another job in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486244/how-to-pass-build-artifact-into-another-job-in-jenkins)

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't want to change parameters in downstream job.